# blender: locking creation radius to mouse movement

Tags: python, scripting, blender

I am try to create a 'bullet time' style camera path for an addon I am building. I would like to create the spherical spiral and then interactive adjust the radius to fit the 'stage.' How can I immediately lock the radius value to the mouse movement and then click complete (kind of like 3ds max creations)? Also, is it possible to remove half the spiral below the 'stage'?

I unfortunately have no code reference outside of the simple creation, I don't even know where to start and google has helped exactly nill on this one :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion is to use a [modal operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html#modal-execution), this can allow you to continue to alter the object after the initial creation until an action accepts or cancels your new object.

For a working example of something more complex, enable the archipack addon that is included with blender, then choose *Add->Mesh->Archipack->Wall*, the new wall has measurements shown around it, you can continue to adjust the object by changing the length, height, angle and number of walls, even after you do other things. You will need to find the addon scripts in blenders installation or in the [git repo](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/archipack/) and look through it to see how it works.

Comment: THIS very well might be exactly what I needed!! Thank you so much. I am going to rip into the archipack addon as well and see if I can glean more out of it. If nothing else you have given me the first solid footing for moving forward, I appreciate you taking to time to answer this for me!

Comment: @XaberTheBlade once you start your addon, have a look at [blender.stackexchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com/) for questions with blender scripting.

Comment: I didn't even know there was an SE just for blender!! Thank you for this, exceedingly helpful :)